# Rails time_select avoid pre-filled and storing on ddbb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my time select is being pre-filled with the current hour:

```
<%= form.time_select :afterstart,  class: "form-control" %>
```

[image]

How can I have a blank placeholder (default to null) so it doesn't get stored in ddbb unless the user fills it in?

Couldn't find any usable method in the API docs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `include_blank: true` to avoid pre-filled

```rb
<%= form.time_select :afterstart,  include_blank: true, class: "form-control" %>
```

but the `time_select` helper will automatically add default time, so the attribute `afterstart` of your model still be saved to db, to avoid this, you can merge your model params with blank `afterstart(1i)` to `afterstart(3i)`

```rb
# your-model controller
private

def your_model_params
 params.require(:your_model).permit(...,:afterstart).merge!({
   "afterstart(1i)": "",
   "afterstart(2i)": "",
   "afterstart(3i)": ""
 })
end
```

so that if user does not select time, that mean `afterstart(4i)` and `afterstart(4i)` blank -> your model `afterstart` will be `nil` and not to be saved to db.

another way is to check if 4i && 5i blank then reject all params keys start with `afterstart`.